# HTTP 404 in my first Sevlet program

Tags: java, servlets

Hello I am a beginner programmer.I am trying to learn Servlet. I am just trying to print a single sentence in a web page. But constantly getting this output on webpage- `**HTTP Status 404**` .Here is my entire coding. My servlet class name is MyGenericServlet.java

```
    package demowebapp1;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;


    public class MyGenericServlet extends GenericServlet {

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)      throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    ServletOutputStream out=response.getOutputStream();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("Jai Hanumanji");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("</html>");
    out.close();

   }

 }
```

and my web.xml page is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"    version="3.1">
   <display-name>demowebapp1</display-name>

   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>mygenser</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>demowebapp1.MyGenericServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>mygenser</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/mygenservlet</url-pattern>

   </servlet-mapping>
   </web-app>
```

although I have gone through all the stackoverflow solutions and tried for those possible solutions still I am getting this Error. May be I am  over looking something.Please help me to figure this out. I am using Tomcat version 8.0.26

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have any exception thrown in your tomcat logs? If yes please provide them?
2. What url are you htting? Are you hitting url `http://localhost:8080/youapp_context/urlpattern` which in your case will be `http://localhost:8080/demowebapp1/mygenservlet`

Comment: I am hitting http://localhost:8087/demowebapp1/mygenservlet and yes as I am keep trying to solve this problem my tomcat server is showing  HTTP Status 404 and my browser is showing often throwing an exception ClassNotFoundException for MyGenericServlet.java. But it is already in  the package demowebapp1. Still I am getting this problem.Another important thing to mention that my src folder is in the root folder of my project and the web.xml file is in Web-INF folder .I didn't change anything.

Comment: Please paste the exception above in the question. Put a debug point at the statement below and restart your server in debug mode. Right click on your project --> Debug on Server. Go ahead and hit the url and see if your debug point is hit.

    response.setContentType("text/html");

Comment: No it's not hitting response.setContentType("text/html").What should I do?

Comment: What's the exception you have?

Comment: I don't know what exactly going on my code but when I completely did it  fresh again it works properly!!! although there is no single difference between the two codes as per my concern. Now it is going fine. Thanks for your help.